# How make publisher known in Setup.exe file using code sign certificate(.cer) file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssl, certificate, code-signing, pfx

I have Code Sign certificate(.cer) file which is provided by client. I want to sign my `.exe` file using it. I have searched lot on google for code signing using `signtool.exe` And followed [this link](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/codesigning101/).

But in every post they ask to have `.pfx` file. While I try to create `.pfx` file from `.cer` file it is not giving me any kind of option to create `.pfx` file.

Then I followed another blog. In that they told me to create .pfx file I have to create .pvk file and .spc file.

To create `.spc` file I used

```
cert2spc myCertificate.cer mySPCFile.spc
```

To create `.pvk` file I used

```
makecert -sv mypvkfile.pvk mycerfile.cer
```

But when I create `.pvk` file using this command the information in the `.cer` file and `.pvk` file are changed. Then I came to know that this command creates the certificate file.

I user below command to create `.pfx` file.

```
pvk2pfx -pvk mypvkfile.pvk -pi mypassword -spc myspcfile.spc -pfx mypfxfile.pfx
```

The `.pfx` file was created successfully And code signing was also successfully done.
**But when I install my .exe file to other machine it was still giving me `Publisher : Unknown`.**
Then I checked properties of my `.exe` file from there in to Digital Signatures tab I see my certificate then I have manually install it to the machine and After that I install my app and find that publisher came but it was not the excet information which `.cer` file was containing before.

My issues are:

1. **How can I create .pfx file from .cer file. Export option is not working with this .cer certificate which is provided by client?**
2. **Is there any other ways to create `.pvk` file from `.cer` file?**
3. **How can I create .pvk file which do not change information of the .cer file?**
4. **Am I doing anything wrong in my above process?**